# About continuity of homotopy mapping(algebraic topology}

Tags: general-topology

Definition of homotopy : Let  $X,Y$ be two topological spaces and $f,g: X\to Y$ be two continuous maps. We say that $f$ is homotopic to $g$ if there exist a continuous map $F: X\times I\to Y$ such that $F(x,0)= f(x),~ F(x,1) = g(x)$ for all $x\in X.$ Then F is called a homotopy from $f$ to $g.$
Again we know that for each $t\in I,$ the map $i_{t} : X\to X\times I$ defined by $i_{t}(x) = (x,t)$ is an embedding. so $f_{t} = F\circ i_{t}: X\to Y$ is a family of continuous maps $X$ to $Y,$ where $t$ runs over the interval $I.$ Thus $F,$ is a simply a family of continuous maps from $X$ to $Y.$

My confusion is that ' will F continuous?
Actually $F(x,0),~F(x,1)....$ and so one, are continuous but I think the mapping $F$ is not continuous beacuse its simply a family of continuous functions.
If $F: X\times I\to Y$ is continuous then how we can prove this when we slove a particular problems? Plz help.

If $F$ is continuous then how to prove it for below example?
we take two continuous functions $f, g:R→R$
by $f(x)=x$
and $g(x)=2x$
and $F:X×I→Y$
define by $F(x,t)=(1−t)f(x)+tg(x)$
then how can we prove that $F$ will be continuous by definition of open set of continuity. ?

Comment: If $F$ is a homotopy then, for each $t\in I$, the map $F_t:X\to Y$ given by $F_t(x) = F(x,t)$ is continuous. The converse is not true in general (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104515/path-homotopy-and-separately-continuous-functions)), although both notions are equivalnt for nice families of spaces (e.g. CW-complexes)

Comment: Yes, $F$ is continuous. It says so right at the start. The text, "is simply a family of continuous maps" is really a misstatement.  $F$ is definitely a family of continuous maps, or at least is associated with such a family, but it is stronger than that, so "simply" seems like the wrong word.

Comment: It's more like $F$ is simply a family of continuous maps glued together **in a parallel manner**, since we need to ensure it's continuous on all of $X \times I$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews, if F is continuous then  the inverse image $ F^{-1} ( V)$ is an open  set in $X\times I$ for all  open set $V $ in $Y.$  How can you sure that ? Actually I am facing a problem when  slove any question.  Plz tell me .

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen sir , If we take two continuous functions $f,~g: \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x) =2x$  and $F:X\times I \to Y$ define by $F(x,t)= (1-t) f(x) + t g(x)$ then how can we prove that F will be continuous by definition of open set of continuity. ?

Comment: Your map $$F:\Bbb R\times I\to\Bbb R,(x,t)\mapsto(1+t)x$$ is polynomial hence continuous.

Comment: I mean, how do you prove any function is continuous? Do you know the product topology on $X\times I?$

Comment: Build it up slowly. The sum of continuous functions is continuous. So, check $(x,t)\mapsto(1-t)f(x)$ is continuous and similarly for $tg(x)$. But wait, the product of continuous functions is also continuous, so check $(x,t)\mapsto(1-t)$ is continuous etc.

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews, The product topology on $X\times I$ is the topology gerenrated by $U\times I$, where $U\in\tau^{X}.$ So how we can show that $F^{-1}(V)\in \tau^{X}\times\tau^{I},$ for any open set $V$ in $Y$

Comment: @Fshrike, I know the proof which was done by you. But we want to prove the continuity by taking inverse image of open set is belong to $\tau^{X}\times\tau^{I}.$

Comment: Ok, but this is proving it by that. The nice thing about theorems is they give you stuff more powerful than just the definition itself. You can explicitly unwind the proofs, if you want, to ‘prove by open set’